Vertex AI - The token is not valid or not have permission
I’ve been trying to deploy Llama 3 from Hugging Face on Google’s Vertex AI (from the Model Garden) but I can’t do it as I keep getting an error with my access token. Google keeps telling me that ‘The token is not valid or not have permission’.
I’ve tried read only tokens, write tokens, fine-grained tokens with all permissions enabled and just can’t get it to work.
